# Need help with generating a bi-phasic current

Tags: signal, measurement, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I'm trying to generate a symmetric biphasic current pulse using a Grass S88 Stimulator.

Here's a diagram:

[image]

SG is a signal generator with two outputs, S1 and S2, which are generating a periodic pulse wave (same period in both). SIUs are transformers to isolate the signal. One of the SIUs is set to reverse the polarity of the input. CCUs are constant current units that as supposed to (I think) convert the voltage signal to a current signal.

I need a biphasic current output so I need to combine the outputs of the two CCUs somehow. How should this be done? How do I get my final biphasic current as given in the diagram?
Also, what should be done to ensure that S1 and S2 are exactly out of phase? I don't want amplitudes cancelling each other out.

Comment: This site is for design issues, NOT the configuration and setup of a specific device.  The idea is to provide a catalogue of questions and answers that helps people in the future with their design issues. Please see the FAQ here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq which outlines the type of questions suitable.

Comment: How much amplitude do you need (max) and what are you driving the current into (though)? -- what is your load? I'm assuming this is a life-science application?

Comment: These (medical?) gadgets look really beautiful, but we can only help when you offer some more general info. Medical? Muscle stimulus? Abstraction - What is an S88? Block diagram of your setup?

Comment: @DrFriedParts I've added a diagram of the application to better explain the problem. I just want to know how to add the currents i1 and i2 to get my biphasic current I.

Comment: If they are truly current sources then you can just wire them together.  An ideal current source has infinite impedance, a very good one will have vey high impedance and high voltage compliance.